# Question of deleted user shown

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-accounts

I saw a question and at end of question there is name of person who asked the question but this name is not clickable as normally it is. So I guess this user is deleted, so my question is: **if this user is deleted why this question is being shown?**

Also, if I click start bounty I am presented with the popup to start bounty. So is this all right? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112893/empty-response-during-ajax-request-in-chrome-but-not-ie-nor-ff) is link to question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So is this all right?

Yes, this is fine.

That a user is deleted (or otherwise disassociated from the post), doesn't mean the post is bad and should be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

The user has been deleted. The question hasn't. The question should act as any other question in the system would, but it will never have an "accepted" answer. So, yes, you can add a bounty to it if you like.